# PHP parallel or series process execution?

Tags: php, mysql

OK maybe this is a dumb question but, if two users execute a php function on a webserver at the same time is this process run in parallel as in side by side but indenpendantly of each other or do they run in series as in one after the other?

Comment: each request uses its own thread/process (depending on webserver) so they run in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to whatever web server / CGI plugin you're using to determine how requests are handled. It's relatively common to give each request its own process (or at least thread) which means they'll be running in pseudo-parallel.

Answer (score 1):

In parallel. Because is a thing about `processor` behaviour and not about parallel code. The processor execute in `parallel`. And about the session behaviour that is common to all pages is sure parallel too. You need to care about concurrence problems related.